# JavaScript - Cambiar color de casillas de grid cuando pase por encima con el raton clicado

Tags: javascript, eventos, events

Tengo un grid en el que quiero que cuando pase sobre las casillas vayan cambiando de color *si el ratón esta clicado*.

He probado con el `onMouseDown()` y con el `onClick()`, pero esto me sirve solo para cuando clico en una casilla en concreto, y no para ir cambiandoles el background-color por todas las que pase con el raton clicado (como si fuera un paint).

¿Alguien sabe como podría hacer algo asi? Llevo un rato buscando y nada

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que "recordar" si el botón está pulsado o no:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell')

let mouseClicked=false
grid.addEventListener('mousedown', e => mouseClicked=true)
grid.addEventListener('mouseup', e => mouseClicked=false)

function changeColor(element) {
  if (mouseClicked) element.style.backgroundColor='yellow'
  //else element.style.backgroundColor='green'
}
cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mousemove',() => changeColor(cell)))
```

```css
div.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 240px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid .cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buaa! perfecto, gracias!